# How do I make a Mach-O binary from an object file?

Tags: macos, linker

I have an object file, which I'd like to make into a Mach-O binary(I'm on Mac OS 10.6). Running `ld -e _main source.o /usr/lib/libc.dylib` produces the following output:

```
ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not defined (usually in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o) for inferred architecture x86_64
```

How can I reference libc using ld?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add to the `ld` invocation the libraries that your object file calls to -- in static or dynamic form. For `printf`, in particular, I think you want `/usr/lib/libc.dylib`.

Comment: If I do `ld -e _main source.o /usr/lib/libc.dylib `, I get `ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not defined (usually in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o) for inferred architecture x86_64`.

Comment: @Mike, so you also need `/usr/lib/crt1.o` in your `ld` command line.

Comment: The linking worked, but I'm getting a segfault:

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff5fc0ff75 in __dyld_stub_binding_helper_interface ()

Comment: @Mike, sorry, I'm out of ideas (I don't know what else is missing in terms of `ld` options or arguments).

Comment: Found the issue - I was specifying my own entry point, which prohibited the libc initializers from running. Taking out the -e arg solved the problem!